# Merge two mp3 audio files into one

Tags: c#, .net, mp3

I have two audio files that I need to merge on top of each other. Each mp3 is one side of a conversation, so in theory when I merge these two files together I should hear a complete conversation. Has anybody ever accomplished this in .Net?

**I've seen examples of people concatenating audio files together, but I repeat, I don't want to do that. I want to merge/mix two audio tracks so the are on the same audio file.**

Any help would be appreciated.

I am looking at the NAudio library. Actual code answers would be very helpful as well.

Comment: Sigh.... Maybe I should bold the part about not wanting to concatenate the two audio files... I want to overlap them on top of each other.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266246/mixing-multiple-audio-samples-into-single-file-with-c

Comment: related (using Delphi) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263680/how-to-mix-mp3-files

Comment: @yms that is closer, but the problem is he is merging the audio streams into a speaker and they have to be 32bit wav files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using Sox to do the merge.

http://sox.sourceforge.net/

sox.exe -m fileone.mp3 filetwo.mp3 output.mp3

Sox doesn't have support for mp3s so you need to download this version which has those references compiled into the executable. Additionally you can search for the dll and the latest should pick them up.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Compiling_SOX_with_Lame.aspx

Use a Process class to call this from .Net.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started with nAudio.

- Convert the mp3's to wav32*
- Mix the 2 wav ([check this code](http://blog.hearablog.com/2010/01/mixing-audio-in-c-using-naudio/))
- Convert the mixed wav to mp3*

*the samples/discussion at nAudio shows how to convert between formats